# Reverse Polish to infix

Tags: notation

I have to convert "A = B C + D E + ×" from reverse polish notation to infix. I'm a bit confused because of the equals sign. Is that an operator too?

This is my answer: A = (B+C) × (D+E)
Is this correct or would this be written another way?

Comment: Yes, from the context it seems clear that your interpretation is correct. It should have been "A B C + D E + x =".

Comment: @D.W. The question asks whether $=$ should be treated as an element of the reverse Polish notation. That seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: Regardless of whether `=` is a comparison or an assignment operator, the infix expression looks fine. The RPN looks off: a) if `=` consumes more than one operand, it is not valid. If it is and has any results at all, these remain on the stack "under" the result of the multiplication at the end of an evaluation.